# How to retain a DOM element in Mithril, across redraws

Tags: mithril.js, virtual-dom

I would like to find out, in Mithril, what is the best practice for preserving a DOM element across redraws.

I have an iframe which contains a link for naviagtion as it's content.
I need to preserve this iframe across Mithril's redraws.

I've tried the following solution where the iframe is being rendered with it's redraw.stategy set to 'none' in the compoent's controller function.

```
var iframeComponent = {
     controller: function() {
         m.redraw.strategy("none") 
     },

     view: function() {
              return m('.backpane-container', [
        m('iframe#bpaneId.backpane-frame[frameborder=0][scrolling=yes]', {

          'src': url,
          'config': configureBackPane.bind(this, controller)
        }),

      ]);
     }
```

However, the iframe appears to be changing across redraws:

Is this the correct way to go about retaining a DOM element..? Or is there a
another approach to achieving this?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a JS fiddle of this behavior. In the meantime, you could try using {subtree: "retain"}. see: https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.render.html#subtree-directives

Comment: Try looking at mithril components see:https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/components.html

Answer (score 3):

In your case you can use the `key`-attribute to preserve the iframe element.  It connects the DOM-nodes to the vDOM-nodes. So even if they change position, the nodes are shifted in place and will not recreated.

see [here](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.html#dealing-with-sorting-and-deleting-in-lists) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the order of the sibling elements where the iframe was being added to the virtual DOM. This was causing the diff engine to redraw.

Changing the order in which the DOM elements being rendered fixed my problem.